# ModelManagerException: Failed to create object

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using `Sonata Admin` bundle. When I submit a "Create entity" form the `ModelManagerException` is thrown if the form has some empty fields.

I've tracked this down to the `PDOException` that is thrown first. The exception is thrown because my empty fields get null values, but my table does not allow null values. I don't want to have null fields, I want empty string instead. How do I tell `Sonata Admin` class to create new entity with empty strings instead of nulls for fields without values?

This is the query that throws the exception:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (name, username, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "my name", "test@mailinator.com"]
```

These are the exceptions:

```
ModelManagerException: Failed to create object: Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\SomeEntity
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null
```

I tried setting `$this->name = '';` explicitly in `SomeEntity` constructor but it didn't help. The query still had `null` instead of `''`. I tried overriding `getNewInstance()` on my `Admin` class to set `name` to `''` value, but it didn't help either - query still had `null` instead.

The weird thing is that I can have empty fields on entity edit form - the entity updates fine and empty fields are saved correctly to the database. Why is this happening?

Example code:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="some_table")
 */
class SomeEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * We can't use Assert\NotNull()
     * because Admin bundle uses null values for empty fields!
     */
    protected $name;

    // Other fields and methods.
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you add the declaration of your entity "some_table" and especially the field "name" in Resources/config/doctrine/.. ?

Comment: @sAr I'm using annotations. I've added part of the entity for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices:

1- if you want the name field can be null, you need to edit the name annotation:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;
```

2- if you want the name field be just an empty string when you create new instance, you just have to add the prePersist in your entityAdmin:

```
    public function prePersist($object)
    {
        $object->setName('');
    }
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There is some DBAL exception associated with this. Scroll lower on the symfony exception page and you'll see it.